# simply access members of other namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope

I am using the famous module pattern for creating namespaces however its cumbersome to write ns1.ns2.member to access a member from ns3(ns1.ns2.ns3).
I do not like using a shortcut var(_ns2=ns1.ns2) for this purpose also *with* statement considered harmfull so what is the better to handle this problem?
is it possible to combine scope of namespaces or whatever? thanks.

```
var NS1 = (function ()
{
    function $(id)
    {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }    

    return {
        $: $
    }
})();


NS1.NS2 = function()
{
    function someFunc()
    {
        // Do not want the below one.
        NS1.$('...');
        // Is there a way to access $ directly.
        // without defining a variable for it here or using with statement.
    }
}();
```

Comment: Some sort of link to material describing this allegedly famous "module pattern" might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what you're talking about, and even if I make believe I do I don't see what's so bad about "ns1.ns2.ns3", but here are a couple of ideas:

```
(function(tempNamespace) {
  blahBlah(tempNamespace.something, tempNamespace.somethingElse);
  // ...
})(ns1.ns2.ns3);
```

Or combine a few:

```
var nsCombined = $.extend({}, ns1, ns2, ns3); // jQuery
```

Some description of what it is you're doing with these namespaces and how much code we're talking about would be useful. I find that once you start using something like jQuery, for most pages — even with fairly complicated client-side behavior — the need for large long-term data structures goes way down.